# Wait for PsExec calling cmd /c to finish in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, return-value, psexec

I have a dynamically generated batch file that I push out to a remote PC and then execute it using PsExec. The issue I am facing is that as soon as that line is called, the PowerShell script moves on and doesn't wait for it to finish. Here is what I have:

```
psexec -accepteula \\$Server -u Username -p Password-d -i 2 cmd /c C:\Call.bat
```

`Call.bat` calls an executable on the remote machine with a few parameters passed in. This file is dynamically generated and is different every time, but can look like this:

```
cd C:\20161212-175524
C:\20161212-175524\RE.exe /pa1 /pa2 /pa3 /pa4 /pa5 /pa6 /pa7 /pa8 /pa9 /pa10
```

The batch file needs to run as an interactive script as that specific user, but I need it to at least wait for the spawned process to finish. I have tried adding `2>&1` and `| Out-Null`

Ideally, I would like to retrieve the exit code returned by the spawned process, but that may be too much.

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Please edit the question to show the PowerShell code that is used to invoke the `psexec` command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously i have used something like this to achieve the waiting you are after:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\tools\PSexec.exe' -ArgumentList "-u MyUserName -p $password \\$Computer .\Run.bat $Var >> C:\Temp\$Computer.log" -Wait -Passthru -WindowStyle Hidden
```

What you need to focus on the line above is by using the `Start-Process` cmdlet we can use the 
`-Wait` parameter.

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string ExecuteAndGetOutput(string command)
{
    string resultFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    string commandFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(resultFile) + ".bat");

    command += @" >""{0}""";
    command = string.Format(command, resultFile);
    File.WriteAllText(commandFile, command);

    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = commandFile;
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Process p = Process.Start(psi);
    p.WaitForExit();

    int exitCode = p.ExitCode;
    return File.ReadAllText(resultFile);            
}
```

Comment: Wrong language...?^^